# Jarallax Scrolling Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use paralax scrolling on my web page, after some searching I found the [jarallax](http://www.jarallax.com/) library. I want to use [demo2](http://www.jarallax.com/demo2/) with the scroll bar effect for my scrolling method, but the scrollbar button does not work.

Here is my JavaScript:

```
init = function () {
var keys = { 38: -0.01, 40: 0.01 };

var drag_controller = new ControllerDrag('buttontodrag', 100, 200);
var key_controller = new ControllerKeyboard(keys, true, true);
var wheel_controller = new ControllerMousewheel(0.01, true);

var jarallax = new Jarallax([drag_controller, key_controller, wheel_controller]);

//defaults
jarallax.setDefault('h1, h2, #p1, #p2, #p3', { display: 'none' });
jarallax.setDefault('#head1, #head2, #head3, #head4, #head5, #head6, #head7 h2, h3, #p1, #p2, #p3, #p4, #p5, #p6, #p7', { opacity: '0' });

//title
jarallax.addAnimation("h1", [{ progress: "0%", opacity: "0" },
                             { progress: "5%", opacity: "1" },
                             { progress: "9%", opacity: "1" },
                             { progress: "12%", opacity: "0" }]);
jarallax.addAnimation("h1", [{ progress: "0%", marginTop: "150px", display: "block" },
                             { progress: "12%", marginTop: "160px" }]);

////slide1
//jarallax.addAnimation(".arrow", [{progress:"20%", top:"-20px"}, {progress:"50%", top:"1px"}]);
//jarallax.addAnimation(".arrow", [{progress:"20%", opacity:"0"}, 
//                                 {progress:"30%", opacity:"1"},
//                                 {progress:"40%", opacity:"1"},
//                                 {progress:"50%", opacity:"0"}]);

jarallax.addAnimation("#head1, #p1", [{ progress: "12%", display: "block", marginTop: '0px' }, { progress: "21%", marginTop: '10px' }]);
jarallax.addAnimation("#head1, #p1", [{ progress: "14%", opacity: "0" },
                                      { progress: "17%", opacity: "1" },
                                      { progress: "19%", opacity: "1" },
                                      { progress: "21%", opacity: "0" }]);

////slide2
//jarallax.addAnimation(".question", [{ progress: "20%", marginLeft: "400px" }, { progress: "30%", marginLeft: "380px" }]);
//jarallax.addAnimation(".question", [{ progress: "22.5%", opacity: "0" },
//                                 { progress: "25%", opacity: "1" },
//                                 { progress: "27.5%", opacity: "1" },
//                                 { progress: "30%", opacity: "0" }]);

jarallax.addAnimation("#head2, #p2", [{ progress: "24%", display: "block", marginTop: '0px' }, { progress: "34%", marginTop: "10px" }]);
jarallax.addAnimation("#head2, #p2", [{ progress: "27%", opacity: "0" },
                                      { progress: "29%", opacity: "1" },
                                      { progress: "31%", opacity: "1" },
                                      { progress: "34%", opacity: "0" }]);

//slide3                                 
jarallax.addAnimation("#head3, #p3", [{ progress: "37%", display: "block", marginTop: '0px' }, { progress: "47%", marginTop: '10px' }]);
jarallax.addAnimation("#head3, #p3", [{ progress: "39%", opacity: "0" },
                                      { progress: "41%", opacity: "1" },
                                      { progress: "44%", opacity: "1" },
                                      { progress: "47%", opacity: "0" }]);

jarallax.addAnimation("#head4, #p4", [{ progress: "51%", display: "block", marginTop: '0px' }, { progress: "61%", marginTop: '10px' }]);
jarallax.addAnimation("#head4, #p4", [{ progress: "54%", opacity: "0" },
                                      { progress: "57%", opacity: "1" },
                                      { progress: "59%", opacity: "1" },
                                      { progress: "61%", opacity: "0" }]);

jarallax.addAnimation("#head5, #p5", [{ progress: "64%", display: "block", marginTop: '0px' }, { progress: "74%", marginTop: '10px' }]);
jarallax.addAnimation("#head5, #p5", [{ progress: "67%", opacity: "0" },
                                      { progress: "69%", opacity: "1" },
                                      { progress: "71%", opacity: "1" },
                                      { progress: "74%", opacity: "0" }]);

jarallax.addAnimation("#head6, #p6", [{ progress: "77%", display: "block", marginTop: '0px' }, { progress: "87%", marginTop: '10px' }]);
jarallax.addAnimation("#head6, #p6", [{ progress: "79%", opacity: "0" },
                                      { progress: "81%", opacity: "1" },
                                      { progress: "84%", opacity: "1" },
                                      { progress: "87%", opacity: "0" }]);

jarallax.addAnimation("#head7, #p7", [{ progress: "89%", display: "block", marginTop: '0px' }, { progress: "100%", marginTop: '10px' }]);
jarallax.addAnimation("#head7, #p7", [{ progress: "91%", opacity: "0" },
                                      { progress: "94%", opacity: "1" },
                                      { progress: "97%", opacity: "1" },
                                      { progress: "100%", opacity: "0" }]);

}
```

And here is my HTML:

```
  <script>
    window.onload = init();
</script>

<div class="containers">
    <div class="span7">
        <%-- Add Paralax here --%>
        <%-- <div class="containers" id="slide1">--%>
        <div id="animation">
            <h1 style="margin-top: 150px;">TimeLine</h1>
            <section id="C2007">
                <%--data-type="background" data-speed="10">--%>
                <h3 id="head1">2007</h3>
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <article id="p1">
                        The Department of Communications announces its commitment to a digital broadcasting platform in South Africa. 
                    At the Commonwealth Telecommunications Organisation’s (CTO) Digital Switchover Forum, the Department of Communications announces its commitment to digital broadcasting in South Africa. 
                    This will place it at the forefront of digital broadcasting worldwide.The Department of Communications announces its commitment to a digital broadcasting platform in South Africa. At the Commonwealth Telecommunications Organisation’s (CTO) Digital Switchover Forum, the Department of Communications announces its commitment to digital broadcasting in South Africa. This will place it at the forefront of digital broadcasting worldwide.  The Department of Communications announces its commitment to a digital broadcasting platform in South Africa. At the Commonwealth Telecommunications Organisation’s (CTO) Digital Switchover Forum, the Department of Communications announces its commitment to digital broadcasting in South Africa. This will place it at the forefront of digital broadcasting worldwide. 
                    </article>
                </div>
            </section>
            <%-- <div class="containers" id="slide2">--%>
            <section id="C2008" style="margin-top: -100px;">
                <%--data-type="background" data-speed="10">--%>
                <h3 id="head2">2008</h3>
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <article id="p2">
                        The Department of Communications announces its commitment to a digital broadcasting platform in South Africa. 
                    At the Commonwealth Telecommunications Organisation’s (CTO) Digital Switchover Forum, the Department of Communications announces its commitment to digital broadcasting in South Africa. 
                    This will place it at the forefront of digital broadcasting worldwide.The Department of Communications announces its commitment to a digital broadcasting platform in South Africa. At the Commonwealth Telecommunications Organisation’s (CTO) Digital Switchover Forum, the Department of Communications announces its commitment to digital broadcasting in South Africa. This will place it at the forefront of digital broadcasting worldwide.  The Department of Communications announces its commitment to a digital broadcasting platform in South Africa. At the Commonwealth Telecommunications Organisation’s (CTO) Digital Switchover Forum, the Department of Communications announces its commitment to digital broadcasting in South Africa. This will place it at the forefront of digital broadcasting worldwide.
                    </article>
                </div>
            </section>
            <%--<div class="containers" id="slide3">--%>
            <section id="C2009" style="margin-top: -100px;">
                <%--data-type="background" data-speed="10">--%>
                <h3 id="head3">2009</h3>
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <article id="p3">
                        The Department of Communications announces its commitment to a digital broadcasting platform in South Africa. 
                    At the Commonwealth Telecommunications Organisation’s (CTO) Digital Switchover Forum, the Department of Communications announces its commitment to digital broadcasting in South Africa. 
                    This will place it at the forefront of digital broadcasting worldwide.The Department of Communications announces its commitment to a digital broadcasting platform in South Africa. At the Commonwealth Telecommunications Organisation’s (CTO) Digital Switchover Forum, the Department of Communications announces its commitment to digital broadcasting in South Africa. This will place it at the forefront of digital broadcasting worldwide.  The Department of Communications announces its commitment to a digital broadcasting platform in South Africa. At the Commonwealth Telecommunications Organisation’s (CTO) Digital Switchover Forum, the Department of Communications announces its commitment to digital broadcasting in South Africa. This will place it at the forefront of digital broadcasting worldwide.
                    </article>
                </div>
            </section>
            <%--</div>--%>
            <%--<div class="containers" id="slide4">--%>
            <section id="C2010" style="margin-top: -100px;">
                <%-- data-type="background" data-speed="10">--%>
                <h3 id="head4">2010
                </h3>
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <article id="p4">
                        The Department of Communications announces its commitment to a digital broadcasting platform in South Africa. 
                    At the Commonwealth Telecommunications Organisation’s (CTO) Digital Switchover Forum, the Department of Communications announces its commitment to digital broadcasting in South Africa. 
                    This will place it at the forefront of digital broadcasting worldwide.The Department of Communications announces its commitment to a digital broadcasting platform in South Africa. At the Commonwealth Telecommunications Organisation’s (CTO) Digital Switchover Forum, the Department of Communications announces its commitment to digital broadcasting in South Africa. This will place it at the forefront of digital broadcasting worldwide.  The Department of Communications announces its commitment to a digital broadcasting platform in South Africa. At the Commonwealth Telecommunications Organisation’s (CTO) Digital Switchover Forum, the Department of Communications announces its commitment to digital broadcasting in South Africa. This will place it at the forefront of digital broadcasting worldwide.
                    </article>
                </div>
            </section>
            <%--<div class="containers" id="slide5">--%>
            <section id="C2011" style="margin-top: -290px;">
                <%--data-type="background" data-speed="10">--%>
                <h3 id="head5">2011
                </h3>
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <article id="p5">
                        The Department of Communications announces its commitment to a digital broadcasting platform in South Africa. 
                    At the Commonwealth Telecommunications Organisation’s (CTO) Digital Switchover Forum, the Department of Communications announces its commitment to digital broadcasting in South Africa. 
                    This will place it at the forefront of digital broadcasting worldwide.The Department of Communications announces its commitment to a digital broadcasting platform in South Africa. At the Commonwealth Telecommunications Organisation’s (CTO) Digital Switchover Forum, the Department of Communications announces its commitment to digital broadcasting in South Africa. This will place it at the forefront of digital broadcasting worldwide.  The Department of Communications announces its commitment to a digital broadcasting platform in South Africa. At the Commonwealth Telecommunications Organisation’s (CTO) Digital Switchover Forum, the Department of Communications announces its commitment to digital broadcasting in South Africa. This will place it at the forefront of digital broadcasting worldwide.
                    </article>
                </div>
            </section>
            <%--</div>--%>
            <%-- <div class="containers" id="slide6">--%>
            <section id="C2012" style="margin-top: -340px;">
                <%--data-type="background" data-speed="10">--%>
                <h3 id="head6">2012</h3>
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <article id="p6">
                        The Department of Communications announces its commitment to a digital broadcasting platform in South Africa. 
                    At the Commonwealth Telecommunications Organisation’s (CTO) Digital Switchover Forum, the Department of Communications announces its commitment to digital broadcasting in South Africa. 
                    This will place it at the forefront of digital broadcasting worldwide.The Department of Communications announces its commitment to a digital broadcasting platform in South Africa. At the Commonwealth Telecommunications Organisation’s (CTO) Digital Switchover Forum, the Department of Communications announces its commitment to digital broadcasting in South Africa. This will place it at the forefront of digital broadcasting worldwide.  The Department of Communications announces its commitment to a digital broadcasting platform in South Africa. At the Commonwealth Telecommunications Organisation’s (CTO) Digital Switchover Forum, 
                    the Department of Communications announces its commitment to digital broadcasting in South Africa. 
                    This will place it at the forefront of digital broadcasting worldwide.The Department of Communications announces its commitment to a digital broadcasting platform in South Africa. 
                    </article>
                </div>
            </section>
            <%-- </div>--%>
            <%--<div class="containers" id="slide7">--%>
            <section id="Current" style="margin-top: -350px;">
                <%-- data-type="background" data-speed="10">--%>
                <h3 id="head7">Current</h3>
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <article id="p7">
                        The Department of Communications announces its commitment to a digital broadcasting platform in South Africa. 
                    At the Commonwealth Telecommunications Organisation’s (CTO) Digital Switchover Forum, the Department of Communications announces its commitment to digital broadcasting in South Africa. 
                    This will place it at the forefront of digital broadcasting worldwide.The Department of Communications announces its commitment to a digital broadcasting platform in South Africa. At the Commonwealth Telecommunications Organisation’s (CTO) Digital Switchover Forum, the Department of Communications announces its commitment to digital broadcasting in South Africa. This will place it at the forefront of digital broadcasting worldwide.  The Department of Communications announces its commitment to a digital broadcasting platform in South Africa. At the Commonwealth Telecommunications Organisation’s (CTO) Digital Switchover Forum, 
                    the Department of Communications announces its commitment to digital broadcasting in South Africa. 
                    This will place it at the forefront of digital broadcasting worldwide.The Department of Communications announces its commitment to a digital broadcasting platform in South Africa. 
                    </article>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div id="scrollbar">
        </div>
        <div id="buttontodrag" href="#">
            ScrollButton            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any Advise to getting the scroll bar button to move while scrolling would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code samples seems to be to long. It is better to use shorter ones and emphasize what is the problem. You can create working example on http://jsfiddle.net/ and add a link. You will be more probable to get an answer.